# Azure Backup Failures

Tags: azure, vss

We use Azure to backup some of our servers. We had 2 servers backing up successfully and tonight had to switch the Azure account they were backing up to - pretty straight forward.

Now the backup services are re-linked; one server is working totally fine and the other is presenting issues.

The backup service fails with a generic error, doing a little digging I was advised to run (Inside Diskshadow):

```
 SET CONTEXT VOLATILE NOWRITERS
 SET METADATA C:\Metadata.cab
 SET VERBOSE ON
 ADD VOLUME C: ALIAS systemVolumeShadow
 BEGIN BACKUP
 CREATE
 END BACKUP
 EXIT
```

This fails with the following error

```
Returned HRESULT: 80042306
Error Text: VSS_E_PROVIDER_VETO
```

Looking in the Event Logs I see this

> The shadow copies of volume c: were aborted because of a failed free space computation.

Extra Info

```
- <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name="volsnap" /> 
  <EventID Qualifiers="49158">20</EventID> 
  <Level>2</Level> 
  <Task>0</Task> 
  <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2014-12-03T22:53:20.407073500Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>519784</EventRecordID> 
  <Channel>System</Channel> 
  <Computer>WIN-GRT860AHGKA</Computer> 
  <Security /> 
  </System>
- <EventData>
  <Data>\Device\HarddiskVolumeShadowCopy4</Data> 
  <Data>C:</Data> 
  <Binary>000000000200300000000000140006C0020000009A0000C003000000000000000000000000000000</Binary> 
  </EventData>
  </Event>
```

Any suggestions?

------ Edit

The machine has around 80gig of spare space.

All the Writers show Stable and No Error.

Answer (score 0):

That error can happen is you have not enougth free space (VSS_E_PROVIDER_VETO) and the shadow copie seem to direct to the same direction.

If you got a lot of free space please run a chkdsk. Last step, run a;

```
vssadmin list writers
```

and make sure they have no error there.

Comment: Thanks, theres around 70 gig of free space. I cant run a CHKDSK at the moment as its a live server, the list writers all comes back stable and no error.